How to configure VS code when the project root directory is not the same as the git repository root?
I'm working with a huge git repository, with many projects in different languages. I am using VS Code to work on just one of them.
Since the git root is different from my project root, I experience a lot of paper-cuts in particular when working with paths and file links. For example, if I use git in the terminal to see the changed files:
> git diff --name-only HEAD~
my_repo/my_project/src/file1
my_repo/my_project/src/file2

If I click on one of these files, VS Code is unable to open it ("No matching results").
I'm sure there must be a single setting which fixes this by letting VS Code know that the project is contained in a directory called my_repo. I've done some searching but I haven't managed to find anything.
